# Getting error while installing kerio VPN

Tags: vpn

when I try to install kerio, the message below appear:

`dpkg: error processing kerio-control-vpnclient-8.1.1-1212-p3-linux.deb (--install):
cannot access archive: No such file or directory`

Errors were encountered while processing:

`kerio-control-vpnclient-8.1.1-1212-p3-linux.deb`

I think the problem is my country filtering, is that possible??? :(
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike `apt-get`, you can't download a package and install it with `dpkg -i`; you should download the `.deb` package first separately and then install it by double clicking it or otherwise using command line methods.

For your specific case with Kerio , follow this [recipe](http://kb.kerio.com/product/kerio-connect/virtual-appliance-linux/installation-on-debian-60-64-bit-amd64-746.html) (which is actually for Debian, and thus I personally got it to work just fine starting from step 6). Then you might also like to take a look at the README on [this page](http://download.kerio.com/dwn/kwf/kerio-kvc.README) for configuring the VPN client on your system.

Comment: thanks bro, I think you are Iranian and as you know these kind of websites are filtered, is there any other way to complete step 6 (Download)?

Comment: No idea really... I think you should look for some third party or unofficial download sources online. Or perhaps your VPN service provider can be a help if you contact them.